# Authenticate user with certificate to WCF service

Tags: wcf, certificate, wcf-security

I was reading an article about authenticating User with certificate to WCF service. Please correct me if I'm wrong. As per my understanding each user need a certificate to authenticate. How feasible is this in real world where, there are multiple clients? Is it good option to adopt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes each user should have his own certificate. Certificate is used for encryption and signing (asymmetric security) and it can be used also for authentication. Authentication can be also provided by another supporting token but that is not supported by default WCF bindings (you must create your own).

To support such scenario you usually need your own certificate authority (CA) which will issue certificates to clients. It can be either use in corporate network where computers usually trusts corporate CA or it can be used over interned but CA's certificate must be issued by well known and trusted certificate authority (like VeriSign).

It is of course feasible in some scenarios. For example banks using client certificates plus some supporting token for connection to internet banking (that is usually web application scenario and not services but it is good B2C example). It is also sometimes used for communication among business partners (E2E / B2B).

Comment: Ladislav, You are the Man. Thanks for another answer. For banks B2C, I'm not sure what you mean? I never did anything on my computer to access my bank account.

Comment: As I know that it is not common in every country but in central Europe you can do almost everything with your bank account (including money transfers) electronically from your computer (or even from mobile if you activate such service). In the same time we have never had (and we will never have) cheques.

Comment: I'm also from Canada. I also do all bank transactions online. My question is regarding the set up of certificate on the client machine. In my case, I never set up anything. Bank Rep set me up and that's it. I didn't do anything on my computer to set up certificate.